# Devise routing error after accidental git rm ./

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I accidentally called `git rm ./ -r` on my working directory and removed all my code. No problems I simply called `git pull` to get the latest code update however now I keep getting a route error from Devise.

After I had to call `bundle install`. From this on I kept getting error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"devise/registrations"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

So first thing i did was to run `rake routes` to see if the route exists and it does:

```
             members_ban GET    /members/ban(.:format)         members#ban
           members_unban GET    /members/unban(.:format)       members#unban
                 members GET    /members(.:format)             members#index
                         POST   /members(.:format)             members#create
              new_member GET    /members/new(.:format)         members#new
             edit_member GET    /members/:id/edit(.:format)    members#edit
                  member GET    /members/:id(.:format)         members#show
                         PUT    /members/:id(.:format)         members#update
                         DELETE /members/:id(.:format)         members#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root        /                              home#index
```

I added the following code `<%= link_to "New", new_user_registration %>` to my Home page view file to see if I can get more info on this:
And I got the following error: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5165745

My routes file:

```
Eveco::Application.routes.draw do

  get 'members/ban'
  get 'members/unban'
  resources  :members
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

**EXPANDED: So I have tracked down the problem via console & error log:**

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 23:51:38 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_bread.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"devise/registrations"}):
  app/views/layouts/_bread.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts__bread_html_erb__280287340_55609968'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:27:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__58597651_53376372'
```

**It would seem there is a problem with the bad way I implemented breadcrumbs for my application. Basically i only want to show controller and method in them so i use this:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %> <span class="divider">/</span></li>

          <% if params[:controller] != 'devise' && params[:controller] != 'users' %>
              <% if params[:controller] != 'home'  %>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <%=
                        link_to params[:controller].to_s.capitalize,
                                :controller => params[:controller]
                    %>
                    <span class="divider">/</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="active">
                    <%= params[:action].to_s.capitalize %>
                  </li>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If i remove this partial from application the routing works like a charm. However now it presents a new problem.

Comment: It sounds like Devise itself isn't installed anymore.  Are you saying you get an error from running `bundle install`?

Comment: Well after I did git pull, I tried running the server and it would not let me until I called bundle install. However when I call `<%= link_to "New", new_user_registration_path %>` I no longer get the error i linked yet the first error i quoted is still there.

Comment: @kellax What did you do to "no longer" get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/763) it could be a problem with namespacing.

Basically I think that `params[:controller]` shows up as `/devise/registrations` because if you look at it that's the way your routes are setup (note the last column), but you have it mapped to `users` so that's what you'd have to use as the controller:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Perhaps it would be better if you could somehow use the url helpers. Perhaps create a hash mapping the breadcrumb text to the url path.

Comment: I expanded my question. Seems it's not a devise/gem problem but rather my own code. Notice this after I took a look in the logs.